# jQuery create element off the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to create an element that will not affect the page in any way, so I don't want to add it to the bottom of the page because it could create a scroll bar. So, I want to add it to the negative-negative area of the screen. How would I go about this?

```
var tempContainer = $("#tempContainer").appendTo("*");
tempContainer.css('position', 'absolute');
tempContainer.css('left', '-9999px');
```

Comment: Set the element with the following CSS: `position: absolute; left: -9999px;`. You could also use `display: none` if you want to guarantee it will never be seen, although that may cause issues if you need to calculate the elements' dimensions.

Comment: `display: none` is the usual approach.

Comment: What Rory suggested above is your best bet. If you are trying to hide, but still call, say, a web bug/tracking pixel, setting to `display:none` will not work because the image won't be loaded. Though, realistically, unless there is something very funky going on with the layout, introducing a single-pixel image shouldn't affect things.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how would I append the element to the DOM?

Comment: @Barmar I can't calculate the width then, which is what I need to do

Comment: Any of the standard jQuery methods would work, `append()`, `appendTo()`, `after()`, `before()`, `insert()`.... check the API.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is the code I added to OP correct?

Comment: @ism: `.appendTo("*")` will append `#tempContainer` to every element on the page. I suspect you don't actually want to do that. I'd use `.appendTo("body")` or `.appendTo(document)` instead. Also, change the  inline style **before** you append to avoid a FOUC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Comment: @pete, if you create an answer, I'll select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new element in jQuery:

```js
var elem = $('<div />'); // or $('<span />') or $('<article />'), etc.
```

To target an existing element by id in jQuery:

```js
var target = $('#tempContainer'); // targets the element with the attribute id="tempContainer"
```

To change an element's styles (inline) in jQuery:

```js
elem.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "top": "0",
    "left": "-9999px"
});
```

To append an element in jQuery:

```js
elem.appendTo(target);

// or

$(target).append(elem);
```

There are other jQuery methods as well, depending on where you want to insert the element. See the following:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/
- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/

Combining all of this into a single chain for an answer:

```js
$('<div />') // create div element
    .attr('id', 'tempContainer') // set id to "tempContainer"
    .css({  // set inline styles
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "0",
        "left": "-9999px"
    })
    .appendTo(document); // append to document
```

You can also do this in native JavaScript (including because the JavaScript tag).

To create a new element in JavaScript:

```js
var elem = document.createElement('div'); // or 'div' or '<article', etc.
```

To target an existing element by id in JavaScript:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('tempContainer'); // targets the element with the attribute id="tempContainer"
```

To change an element's styles (inline) in JavaScript:

```js
elem.style.position = 'absolute';
elem.style.top = '0';
elem.style.left = '-9999px';
```

To append an element in JavaScript:

```js
target.appendChild(elem);
```

Combining all of this into a cohesive group for an answer

```js
var elem = document.createElement('div'); // create element
elem.id = 'tempContainer'; // set id to "tempContainer"
elem.style.position = 'absolute'; // set inline styles
elem.style.top = '0';
elem.style.left = '-9999px';
document.appendChild(elem);
```